# How to use environment variable in js file with gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, environment-variables

I'm helping on the project consisting of html, css and js plugins all built with gulp. The project was bought as a template and customized by our marketing team (yep...) and I'm supposed to help with scripting.

Now there is a plugin which sends form data to server with `$.ajax()` call. Url param is set as a constant, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'exact-api-url',
  type: 'POST'
  ...
});
```

How can I replace it with env variable and where exactly should I store it? There are different URLs for `prod` and `dev`. I want it to look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: environment.API_URL,
  type: 'POST',
  ...
});
```

From solutions I found I got the feeling that they mostly deal with **env** variables within **gulpfile.js** itself not the **js** code in project. One workaround suggested using global **js** variables which I don't like. What's the proper way to do it?

I'm an an Angular/React guy, working mostly with webpack and I find gulp's lack of environment folder disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

Below is one of solution.
You can generate a config file as **config.js** using template **config.tmpl.js**

```
module.exports = <%= url %>
```

Below are my gulp task to set the url for Dev & prod.

```
gulp.task('set-dev-node-env', function() {
    return process.env.url = 'exact-dev-url';
});

gulp.task('set-prod-node-env', function() {
    return process.env.url = 'exact-prod-url';
});
```

Task to generate the **config** file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var template = require('gulp-template');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('config', function() {
    return gulp.src('path/to/config.tmpl.js')
      .pipe(template({url: `${process.env.url}`}))
      .pipe(rename('config.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/config.js'));
});
```

Below are task to build for dev and prod

```
gulp.task('build_for_prod', ['set-prod-node-env','config'], function() {
    runSequence(
        '...buildSteps'
    );
});

gulp.task('build_for_dev', ['set-dev-node-env','config'], function() {
    runSequence(
        '...buildSteps'
    );
});
```

and finally, in your JS file

```
var config = require('path/to/config.js');

$.ajax({
    url: config.url,
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps :)